# Android Palette Trouble Generating

Tags: android

Trying to learn Palette but have run into an error. I am trying to use the generate(). But when I type it out I get a line crossing out the `.generate`. I have been following a tutorial and from my understanding I need this generate function to work in order to get the following function (applyPalette) to populate the colours.

Can anyone offer some assistance? Keeping in mind that I am new to palette and might have missed something small. Thanks

**Generate() Updated and Working**

```
private void colorize(Bitmap photo) {
    Palette palette = new Palette.Builder(photo).generate();
    applyPalette(palette);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for the `generate` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html#generate(android.graphics.Bitmap)):

> **This method is deprecated.**
>
> Use `Palette.Builder` to generate the Palette.

You can find the `Palette.Builder` class reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.Builder.html). The new syntax to synchronously generate a `Palette` instance (mirroring the functionality in your original question) would be:

```
private void colorize(Bitmap photo) {
    Palette palette = new Palette.Builder(photo).generate();
    applyPalette(palette);
}
```

In general, Android Studio marks deprecated methods using a strikethrough, as you saw.

Comment: Ok I see, I have edited the code to `Palette palette = Palette.Builder(photo)` as per the documentation but I got an error saying method call expected?

Comment: Are you also calling one of the `generate` methods ([sync](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.Builder.html#generate()) or [async](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.Builder.html#generate(android.support.v7.graphics.Palette.PaletteAsyncListener))) to actually build the palette?

Comment: The only time I was calling the `generate` was in the above function and then tried to use the palette generated in the `applyPalette` function.

Comment: You should replace that old line with `Palette.Builder(photo).generate()`.

Comment: Trying that I got an error under `Palette.Builder(photo)` saying method call expected?

Comment: I got rid of that error by adding `new` before the `Palette.Builder(photo).generate()`. The only thing is now the `applyPalette` function is still givning me errors for the palette.get functions

Comment: @Hayes121 see updated sample code, does that match what you're doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93929/discussion-between-hayes121-and-stkent).